# MongoDB aggregate for Arithmetic Operations - Subdocument Field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

We have a aggregate query projecting few sub documents. We wanted to apply a few arithmetic operations like Sum and Product on these projected values.

Aggregation Query --

```
Item.aggregate([
        { $unwind: '$dummy'},       
        { $match: {'dummy.storage': {$gt: 0}} },
        { $group: {_id: '$_id',
                    dummy: {$push: '$dummy'},
                    original_y: { $first: "$original_y" },
                    new_y: { $first: "$new_y" },

        }},
        {$project:{
                  original_y: 1, new_y: 1,
                  tallyAmount: {$sum: ["$new_y","$original_y"] }
                }
        },
     ]
    )
    .exec(function(err, results){   
        if(err)
        {
            console.log("Error : " + err);
            return res.json ({error: "Error"});

        }
        else if(!(results) || results == null || results.length == 0)
        {
            console.log("No Results Found");
            return res.json ({error: "No Results Today"});

        }else{

            res.send(results);
        }
    });
```

This gives an error stating
`invalid operator '$sum'`

What should we do to get the sum of `original_y` and `new_y` in the `$project`?

**EDIT**

Documents:

```
{
 id:1,
 original_y: 200,
 new_y: 140,
 dummy: [
  {id:1, storage:2, cost: 10},
  {id:2, storage:0, cost: 20},
  {id:3, storage:5, cost: 30},
  ]
}
```

OUTPUT EXPECTED:

```
 {
     id:1,
     original_y: 200,
     new_y: 140,
     dummy: [
      {id:1, storage:2, cost: 10, tallyAmount: 34},
      {id:3, storage:5, cost: 30, tallyAmount: 11.33},
      ]
    }
```

where,
       `tallyAmount = (original_y + new_y) / cost`

ERROR: can't add an expression for a subfield of dummy because there is already an expression that applies to the whole field

Comment: @chridam Have updated the Document & Expected Output

Comment: Thanks for the update, I've updated my answer below to incorporate the changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without much details of your document schema and the expected aggregation result, I would suggest you try the following aggregation as I believe you need the [**`$add`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) operator rather than the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) operator. Note that the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) operator is only applicable to the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator. With the [**`$add`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) operator, it adds up two numbers/fields together and the result is stored in a new field with the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator:

```
Item.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "dummy.storage": { "$gt": 0 } } },
    { "$unwind": "$dummy" },   
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id", 
        "original_y": { "$first": "$original_y" },
        "new_y": { "$first": "$new_y" }
    } },
    { "$project": {
        "original_y": 1, 
        "new_y": 1,
        "tallyAmount": { "$add": [ "$new_y", "$original_y" ] }
    } }
]).exec(callback);
```

-- **UPDATE** --

To satisfy the condition `tallyAmount = (original_y + new_y) / cost`, you should use the [**`$add`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/#exp._S_add) and [**`$divide`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) arithmetic operators in your $project operator pipeline stage thus your final aggregation pipeline would look like this:

```
Item.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "dummy.storage": { "$gt": 0 } } },
    { "$unwind": "$dummy" },
    {
        "$project": {
            "original_y": 1, 
            "new_y": 1,
            "dummy.id": "$dummy.id",
            "dummy.storage": "$dummy.storage",
            "dummy.cost": "$dummy.cost",
            "dummy.tallyAmount": {
                "$divide": [
                    { "$add": ["$new_y","$original_y"] },
                    "$dummy.cost"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "_$id",
            "original_y": { "$first": "$original_y" },
            "new_y": { "$first": "$new_y" },
            "dummy": {
                "$addToSet": "$dummy"
            }
        }        
    }
 ]).exec(callback);
```

Comment: The only problem is that the 'tallyAmount' field needs to be INSIDE each 'dummy' subdocument. I am facing an error which hasn't been heard of before ever! 

`ERROR: can't add an expression for a subfield of dummy because there is already an expression that applies to the whole field`

Comment: @RohitLala Ok, I have updated my answer with the correct aggregation pipeline that takes into consideration the desired output.